# Cómo imprimir método componentDidMount en html

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {config} from './configuracion/config'
import firebase from  'firebase'
import 'firebase/database'

/*const tabstyleletra = {
  color:'white'
}*/

 class App extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
     super(props)
    this.state = {
     tomas:[]
   }
  this.firebaseapp =firebase.initializeApp(config)
  this.db=this.firebaseapp.database().ref().child('filas')

} 

  componentDidMount(){
   this.db.on('child_added',function(snapshot){
    return snapshot.val().CODIGO
    /*var array=this.state.tomas.slice()
    array.push(snapshot.val().CODIGO )
    this.setState({tomas:array})*/

  })
}

 render(){
    return(
     <div>{this.state.tomas}</div>

  )

 }
}
export default App;
```

Buenas quiero poder imprimir lo que esta dentro del metodo componentDidMount pero en lugar de console.log()  quiero que se pinte en un div a algun html para que se vea en el DOM

Comment: Te refieres a hacer print de la función como tal? (El código de javascript) o hacer print del resultado de tu función (Es decir, lo que retornas en la función)

Comment: Lo que quiero es que los datos se vean en una tabla

Comment: Eso no lo vas a poder hacer, conponentDidMount se usa para controlar datos lo que puedes hacer es llamar a una función y esa función que devuelva el contenido que quieras y lo imprimes en el render.